# Neural Network not learning when has more than 1 hidden layers

Tags: c#, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm implementing my first Neural Network as my end of year high school thesis. I'm getting great results when training it with MNIST dataset. But that is only when I use only 1 hidden layer, if I try to use more than 1 hidden layer after training is always giving the same output.
I tried recalculating the derivatives of the error function with more than one layer but I must be missing something...
Here is the code for my backpropagation method:

```
    public void BackPropagation(double[] error, bool batch)
    {
        double[][] temp = null;
        temp = NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(NNMath.EntryWiseProduct(error, NNMath.SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(this.A[this.A.Length - 1])));
        this.DW[this.DW.Length - 1] = NNMath.TransposeMatrix(NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(temp), NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(this.A[this.DW.Length - 1])));
        temp[0].CopyTo(this.DB[this.DB.Length - 1], 0);

        for (int i = this.W.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            temp = NNMath.DotProduct(temp, NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.W[i]));
            temp = NNMath.EntryWiseProduct(temp, NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(NNMath.SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(this.A[i])));
            if (batch)
            {
                this.DW[i - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DW[i - 1], NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.A[i - 1]), temp));
                this.DB[i - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DB[i - 1], temp[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                this.DW[i - 1] = NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.A[i - 1]), temp);
                temp[0].CopyTo(this.DB[i - 1], 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I've created a static class called NNMath that I use to do matrix operations.

- `this.A` is a 2 dimansional array with every row rappresenting an activation layer.
- `this.W` is a 3 dimensional array where every element is the matrix of the weights between 2 layers.
- `this.DW` is the same of `this.W` but contains the calculated derivatives
- `this.DB` is a 2 dimensional array containing the derivatives of the biases
- `batch` is true if the method is called during a batch training

I'm using MSE as the loss function.

Thanks in advance!

***EDIT:***
Here is some more code from NNMath

```
    public static double[] EntryWiseSum(double[] a, double[] b)
    {
        if (a.Length != b.Length)
            return null;
        double[] c = new double[a.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
                c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        return c;
    }

    public static double SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(double sigmoidA)
    {
        return sigmoidA * (1.0 - sigmoidA);
    }

    public static double[] SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(double[] a)
    {
        double[] res = new double[a.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            res[i] = SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(a[i]);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Does your hadamard product method(`NNMath.EntryWiseProduct(error`) return an array instead of a matrix?

Comment: If the 2 given inputs are arrays than it returns an array, if both are matrices it return a matrix

Comment: Where's your biases, are they just another row in each layer matrix?

Comment: I have a matrix with rows rapresenting the layers and elemnts being the node's bias, the input layer does not have biases

Comment: I'm not sure how you have your dot product implemented but for product multiplication is not cumulative make sure you're multiplying them so they expand going backwards into the layers. Also, you may be multiplying the wrong matrix here `NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.W[i])`, normally you would dot product the gradient with the transposed output of the previous layer you might be meaning to use `this.DW`

Answer (score 0):

I've found my error.
Here is the corrected method if anyone will be wondering.

```
    public void BackPropagationNew(double[] error, bool batch)
    {
        double[][] temp = null;
        temp = NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(NNMath.EntryWiseProduct(error, NNMath.SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(this.A[this.A.Length - 1])));
        if (batch)
        {
            this.DW[this.DW.Length - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DW[this.DW.Length - 1],  NNMath.TransposeMatrix(NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(temp), NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(this.A[this.DW.Length - 1]))));
            this.DB[this.DB.Length - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DB[this.DB.Length - 1], temp[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            this.DW[this.DW.Length - 1] = NNMath.TransposeMatrix(NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(temp), NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(this.A[this.DW.Length - 1])));
            temp[0].CopyTo(this.DB[this.DB.Length - 1], 0);
        }

        for (int i = this.W.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            temp = NNMath.DotProduct(temp, NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.W[i]));
            temp = NNMath.EntryWiseProduct(temp, NNMath.ArrayToMatrix(NNMath.SigmoidDerivativeFromSigmoid(this.A[i])));
            if (batch)
            {
                this.DW[i - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DW[i - 1], NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.A[i - 1]), temp));
                this.DB[i - 1] = NNMath.EntryWiseSum(this.DB[i - 1], temp[0]);
            }
            else
            {
                this.DW[i - 1] = NNMath.DotProduct(NNMath.TransposeMatrix(this.A[i - 1]), temp);
                temp[0].CopyTo(this.DB[i - 1], 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Because I was using mini-batch training and I forgot to check if it was in a batch in the first weights change it beasically wasn't cahnging the weights. Thanks anyway to any one that tried to help me! I'll try to be more careful next time.